# Is python logger thread-safe or not?

Tags: python

Is python logger thread-safe or not? I use python 2.6.

Comment: Why didn't you read this? http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is thread-safe, but there are some cautions in the documentation that you need to be aware of. Search for "thread" in [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Yes it is](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#thread-safety).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be:

http://chrisrbennett.com/2008/04/python-logger-config-thread-safety.html

Not sure he's talking about 2.6 though.